# Integral boundary notation $\int_0^{(1+)}dx~f(x)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, notation

What does the notation for the upper boundary in the following kind of integral mean?

$$\int_0^{(1+)}dx ~f(x)$$

It can be seen [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E2).

Comment: I'm quite sure that $(1+)$ corresponds to $1^+$. See my answer.

Comment: @the_candyman that is not correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the previous answers are correct in some settings, I do not believe that is what is meant [in the case you refer to](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E2).

Instead, I suggest that what is meant is a *loop integral*, and the notation
$$
\int_{0}^{(1+)}
$$
means that the contour they integrate over is starting at $0$, circles $1$ in positive sense (i.e. counter-clock wise) and then returns to $0$. So, why do I believe that? Well, I've seen it before. Also, look at [this page](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12) about the Beta function, In particular [this figure](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.F1).

(The reason why one loops like this might be singularities or branch cuts.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $f(x)$ is well defined for $x=0$. Maybe, $f(x)$ is "strange" when $x = 1$ (i.e. vertical asymptote, jumps, holes...).

Assume also that there exists a function $F(x)$ such that $\frac{d F(x)}{dx} = f(x)$ (i.e., $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$). Then:

$$\int_0^{1^+}dx ~f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x) - F(0).$$

Comment: Oh, that is simple. However, since a single boundary point is a set of zero measure and can always be dropped, I was under the impression that the integral is defined to be $\int_0^1\equiv \lim_{a\to 0}\lim_{b\to 1}\int_a^b$. Am I wrong in thinking this, and if yes, could you elaborate on  a reason why?

Comment: Why do you assume the existence of a primitive? (Or where do you assume its existence?)

Comment: @AhmedHussein Added the existence of a primitive has an hypothesis. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the notation $a^+$ is used as a shorthand for "approaching $a$ from the right". So it suggests, at least to me, that $f(x)$ has some unconventional behaviour at $x = 1$, in particular it may be that $f(x)$ is actually a pseudo-function - for example, it may be related to the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ which is defined such that it is zero everywhere except at $x = 0$, and its integral over any interval containing zero is $1$.

You could represent the Dirac delta's behaviour by writing something like, for example: $\int_{-\infty}^{0^+} \delta(x) dx = 1$, which would just be shorthand for $\forall \epsilon > 0 \int_{-\infty}^{\epsilon} \delta(x) dx = 1$, or the same thing represented as a single-sided limit.